# Picture Library card custom view

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, picture-library

I have a Pictures Library and I want to customize the gallery with cards with picture on top and below the picture some data taken from other columns in the Pictures Library.

I've created a Thumbnail column to have a preview, but when I switch to gallery view I don't understand how to make reference in my JSON to the thumbnail picture.

I've tried using `[$Thumbnail.serverRelativeUrl]` or just `[$Thumbnail]` but
it doesn't work.

Any idea please?

Comment: What is the data type & internal name of your Thumbnail column? How did you create this?

Comment: Column type is "Image" and named  "Thumbnail". Created on the library setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image field object has the following properties (with example values):

```
{
  "fileName": "image.png",
  "id": "6bb1d843-0633-4c9a-9a16-90bc5abd1d8e",
  "serverRelativeUrl": "/teams/Discovery/SiteAssets/Lists/ad6ed939-0db2-4d85-8a39-8f3497f41eee/image.png",
  "serverUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"
}
```

**Sourcee**: [Column formatting - Special string values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#special-string-values) - see "Image fields" section.

So, you should be able to get the URL of image in image column using `@currentField.serverRelativeUrl` or `[$InternalNameOfColumn.serverRelativeUrl]`.

So, Please check if you are using correct **internal name** of your column. Follow below reference to find out the internal of column: [Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

---

**Additional**:

As you are using Picture library (document library), you can try using the in-built token to retrieve the URL to the thumbnail of a image/file instead of creating custom column.

- `@thumbnail.small`, `@thumbnail.medium`, and `@thumbnail.large` evaluate to the thumbnail URL in 3 different predefined sizes.

**Example**:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "img",
   "attributes": {
      "src": "@thumbnail.small",
      "alt": "='Thumbnail of file ' + [$FileLeafRef]"
   },
   "style": {
      "width": "100%",
      "max-width": "100%"
   }
}
```

**Source**: [Column formatting - Thumbnails](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#thumbnails)

Comment: Thank you!! since I'm using a Picture Library `src": "@thumbnail.small` works perfectly.
Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used to make the card shown below.  My example uses a people column to extract the user's name and image and their start date to display in the card, plus a little CSS magix mixed in (border-radius) for rounded corners and the class (ms-bgColor-neutralQuaternaryAlt) for matching the site’s theme.

All in all, this answer has everything you should need to build your own solution to your question.

Exemplar Image:

[image: User Card From A SharePoint List]

***Code Explainer:***

Since we are importing both a way to format the view as well as the row, we need to import both the row and view formatting schema.

The *hideSelection*  and the  *hideListHeader* options are both set to true.

1. *"hideSelction":true* removes the ability for the item to be selected by the end users (who have adequate permissions).  *"hideSelection":true* in addition to the removal of the command bar on a page *effectively* renders the item un-editable for the casual user.
2. *"hideListHeader":true* removes the column labels from the view.

(BTW, both these elements and more can be used on *ANY* list or library view of your choosing, so long as you import the  View *and* Row Formatting schemas, as outlined below.)

3. Next we reference the rowFormatter.  We declare a container element (a DIV) and specify how it should look using the "style" property.  Note:  this is the equivalent of using in-line css on an element.
4. Next we can declare other attributes that would also be in the (normally) in-line HTML , if this were written in HTML.  In this case, we are ascribing values to the *class* attribute.
5. Then we begin enumerating the children elements within the same principles used in the previous two steps.

   5.a:  We create a child DIV that contains the image, set the attributes and style and iterate through the other children of the parent DIV which,  includes an IMG sub-element.

***Documentation for your reference***

1. View Formatting Documentation:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting
2. Column Formatting Documentation:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting
3. List Formatting GitHub:  https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting  This is particularly useful if you go and explore the samples.  you will learn a lot.
4. Finally, just go and read the schemas by navigating to their URLs.  JSON schemas are nothing like XML schemas to read - they are un-junked up text files with normative spacing and other code conventions, without all the impositions XML makes towards self-perfection (e.g.: DTD’s, etc.)  Hell, you might even want to print it out! ;)

   4.a.  https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json

   4.b.  https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json

***Please mark this as an answer if it helped you.***

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideListHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "float": "left",
      "display": "flex",
      "flex-wrap": "wrap",
      "flex-direction": "column",
      "align-items": "center",
      "justify-content": "center",
      "width": "250px",
      "height": "200px",
      "max-width": "250px",
      "max-height": "200px",
      "border-radius": "8px",
      "margin-right": "10px",
      "margin-bottom": "10px",
      "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey",
      "overflow": "hidden"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralQuaternaryAlt ms-fontColor-neutralDark"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "img",
            "style": {
              "display": "block",
              "height": "auto",
              "max-height": "150px",
              "max-width": "150px",
              "border-radius": "50%"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "src": "=@currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=' + [$Employee.email]",
              "title": "[$Employee.Title])"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "text-align": "center",
          "width": "100%",
          "display": "block"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralDark"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "font-weight": "500",
              "font-size": "1.5rem"
            },
            "txtContent": "[$Employee.title]"
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "font-weight": "500",
              "font-size": "1.1em",
              "overflow": "hidden",
              "max-width": "280px",
              "white-space": "nowrap",
              "text-align": "center",
              "margin-bottom": "0.5em"
            },
            "txtContent": "[$Employee.jobTitle]"
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "font-weight": "500",
              "font-size": "1.5em",
              "overflow": "hidden",
              "white-space": "nowrap",
              "text-align": "center"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-bgColor-white ms-fontColor-themePrimary"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "attributes": {
                  "iconName": "AddFavorite"
                }
              },
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "txtContent": " Welcome!"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```